# Post Increment and Pre Increment and Rvals

Tags: compiler-construction, parser-generator, lalr

```
int a;
a = a+++a; // Why does this create no error but
a = a+++++a; // Create a semantic error
```

I'm kind of confused why the second line doesn't create any errors 
but why the third one creates a semantic error?

Comment: Which language are you using? Add it as a tag.

Answer (score 4):

Maximal Munch. The result of a++ is an r-val. The next operator is ++, which tries to increment the r-val and produces an error.